# Minimum Size for Kerem

Tags: halacha, agriculture

If one purchased 5 grape vines in order to make a small vineyard in his back yard, excluding the required 4 amot around the vineyard, what is the necessary procedure? At first I though all one needs to do is plant five vines in two rows with the proper space between each row. Now based on my understanding of Mishnah Kilayim Chpt 4 and Mishneh Torah Kilayim Chpt 7, there must be a minimum spacing of 4 amot between each vine in a given row and 4 amot between rows.

Now, using 50 cm for an amah, this would mean that each row would be 2 m apart and each vine in a row needs to be 2 m apart as well.

So would this mean that if one sets up his vineyard as diagrammed below, he would need to set an area of 4 m by 8 m?

o o o
o o

Comment: What are you asking?  Are you searching the psak of Shulchan Aruch?  Are you searching difference for outside erets israel

Comment: I am looking for the halacha l'maaseh. I am interested in making a halachic vineyard. I don't have much space to work with so I'm trying to determine the absolute minimum size and work up from there.

Comment: CYLOR!!! is the rule. We can say that you want to learn Aliba Dehilcheta.  please edit until they close your question.

Answer (score 1):

I was discussing this with my rabbi over shabbat. He said each row and each vine on a row needs to be 4 amot apart. What he clarified is from where to measure from. I wasn't sure if it's measured from the trunk or the outermost growth. He said from the outermost growth. So it seems that there is a lot more planning involved than just sticking it in the ground.

Comment: מעיקר הגפנים לשדה

Comment: @kouty agreed, my primary concern was the spacing of each grapevine in relation to each other. I edited the question to reflect that.